# The sources of Abraham's wealth

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, abraham, vayera, parashat-lech-lecha

The Torah specifies that Abraham profited well from deceiving Pharaoh and Avimelech by presenting Sarah as his sister:

> וַיַּעַל אַבְרָם מִמִּצְרַיִם הוּא וְאִשְׁתּוֹ וְכָל־אֲשֶׁר־לוֹ וְלוֹט עִמּוֹ הַנֶּגְבָּה׃
> וְאַבְרָם כָּבֵד מְאֹד בַּמִּקְנֶה בַּכֶּסֶף וּבַזָּהָב׃

> From Egypt, Abram went up into the Negeb, with his wife and all that he possessed, together with Lot. Now Abram was very rich in cattle, silver, and gold.

And

> וַיִּקַּח אֲבִימֶלֶךְ צֹאן וּבָקָר וַעֲבָדִים וּשְׁפָחֹת וַיִּתֵּן לְאַבְרָהָם וַיָּשֶׁב לוֹ אֵת שָׂרָה אִשְׁתּוֹ׃

> Abimelech took sheep and oxen, and male and female slaves, and gave them to Abraham; and he restored his wife Sarah to him.

Does the Torah mention other sources of Abraham's wealth?

Answer (score 1):

Not in the Torah per se, but in Midrashic sources e.g. in the [Midrash HaGadol 24:2](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38103&st=&pgnum=203&hilite=) it says that upon leaving Ur Kasdim, all the great men of the nations came to bring Avraham gifts and Nimrod offered him his son Eliezer as a slave.

Comment: There are few other instances listed elsewhere but I will only list them if this answer suffices...i.e. if you 're only looking for sources in the Torah I will delete...

Comment: Does it find any textual hints or just a speculation?